# Naming a software which allows communication between two independent systems via internet

Tags: naming, naming-standards

Probably a trivial question but I just don't know how that piece of software would be called correctly:

I have a closed system (A) and an application on another system and location (B). The Application on System B needs information&data via TCP/IP from the closed system (A). Unfortunately system A doesn't provide an open interface for this puprose. Therefore I have to write a piece of software (C) which is installed at location of system A, retrieves the needed information from system A (e.g. via using a serial port or reading the memory) and sends them via TCP/IP to system B.

How would I call system C?

I would go with [name-here]-Client. But this gives actually no information about what it does. Would I call this an "adapter"? Or an "wrapper"? But I only know these terms from software design patterns. Is this a "middleware" because it allows communication between A and B?

Probably trivial but I would like to know what a good fitting term would be so you can actually guess what it might supposed to do (what you don't know if it is just called a "Client").

Thanks!

Comment: First thing that came to my mind is "proxy", but then I saw that it is not B asking C for data, but C pushing data to B. This might make big difference in naming.

Comment: Yea, I think proxy doesn't really fit because it is actually not a "passive" software component but it rather pulls system A and pushes to system B actively. I also thought about the term "Connector" - but I'm also not sure with this one.

Comment: “probe” springs to mind.

Comment: I would opt for something like One-way sync or mirroring middleware, but this isn't exactly accurate unless you are actually mirroring the data. Perhaps something like Push system/middleware? Though this should only apply if you are actually pushing on a trigger or event, instead of periodically.

Answer (score 0):

In Head first design patterns there's a similar situation in the proxy pattern and they have used the word "helper". 
And yes, I think this is middleware.

Comment: Thanks, helper is not that bad. And cctually it is a good idea to look at the design patterns and see if there is a fit. I came across the mediator pattern which is described as "With the mediator pattern, communication between objects is encapsulated within a mediator object. Objects no longer communicate directly with each other, but instead communicate through the mediato" (Wikipedia). So that also describes pretty well.